# Augmented reality engine with text detection in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, ocr, augmented-reality

I want to create a similar app to "[word lens](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/word-lens/id383463868?mt=8)" anybody know any augmented reality sdk which can detect the text and its location from the camera feed/video? Or anybody can give me any pointer on where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new on character recognition and augmented reality but you can look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) for image recognition.

If you need to detect characters and then translate them. You should search for Optical character recognitions library such as [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/).

I don't know if there is a lot of library that do the trick but you can search on that.

Hope I helped.